# MediaWiki Beautifier PHP package location

Tags: mediawiki

Does anybody happen to know where I can download the Beautifier PHP package for use with MediaWiki for syntax highlighting?

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Syntax_Highlighting - The MediaWiki syntax highlighter  installation article (apparently) has a link to two mirrors with the files, but they don't seem to have them all.

Anybody know where else I can obtain them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this: [Syntaxhighlight](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Syntaxhighlight)?